# Дата и время NOW() не отправляется в mysql базу данных

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть форма testdb c 4 колонками:

```
message_id
name
content
message_date
```

Заполняю их данными из 3 инпутов. В 4 должна проставляться дата и время. Но при добавлении NOW() или CURRENT_TIME() форма отказывается отправляться. Подскажите, где косякнул?
php

```
<?php

try{

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb; charset=utf8;', '****', '****'); 

$msg_id = $conn -> lastInsertId();

$query = "INSERT INTO message VALUES (NULL, :name, :content, :message_id, :message_date, NOW())";
$msg = $conn -> prepare($query);
$msg -> execute(['name' => $_POST['name'], 'content' => $_POST['content'], 'message_id' => $msg_id, 'message_date' => $msg_date]);

}

catch (PDO_Exception $e)
{
echo 'error';
}

?>
```

Если не проставлять NOW () - вместо даты и времени будут 00.00 00.00.00 (ожидаемо)

Comment: в запросе у вас написано и message_date и NOW()

Comment: Измените тип поля `message_date`, установите опцию `DEFALUT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, и вообще не присваивайте значение (даже не упоминайте поле) в запросе. Сервер присвоит правильное значение автоматически. PS. В запросе укажите список конкретных полей для присвоения значений.

Comment: Изменение типа поля не помогает, к сожалению. Сервер автоматом ничего не присваивает - попробовал все опции/комбинации.
К тому же, мне не нужно обновление времени по запросу. Оно должно устанавливаться при запросе и не меняться, для чего NOW() очень даже подходит.